# Adobe InDesign CS5 Scripting - Object does not support the property or method 'resolution'

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript

Ok upgraded to CS5 and now this is not supported:

```
app.jpegExportPreferences.resolution = 350;
```

Question is how to specify resolution in CS5 since this worked in CS4?

Comment: FWIW these days you can also tell IDS to use the object model from a specific version. For instance, for CS5/5.5 use `app.scriptPreferences.version = 7.0;` and then your older code should work. I haven't tried this but came across it in the docs.

Answer (score 4):

figured it out

```
app.jpegExportPreferences.exportResolution = 350;
```

changed to `exportResolution`

Answer (score 0):

Glad you figured it out! Here is a good reference for jpegExportPreferences as well:

http://indesignscriptingreference.com/cs2/javascript-cs2/jpegexportpreference.htm

Hope this helps!

Comment: sigh... it would be sweet if that 6-year-old link wasn't broken. :)

Comment: I should have copy pasted it in :( I'm sorry

Comment: It's okay... still looking for official Adobe docs that mention `jpegExportPreferences.` Funny, even the home page at http://indesignscriptingreference.com/ is a 404